# How to force Android browser to not change viewport's width when zooming in/out?

Tags: android, html, css, viewport, android-browser

I would like to know how to force Android browser (preferably using pure CSS3) to not change viewport's width when user zooms in/out with his/her fingers ?

I have multiple media-queries on page aiming to different viewport widths. But anytime user zooms in/out the page viewport width is changed so layout of the page is reordered and I don't this to happen. I want Android browser to "remember" its initial viewport size and when user zooms in/out I want Android browser to JUST zoom, but not change the viewport size.

Is this possible with CSS ? Thank you for any help in advance.

EDIT: My media queries:

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 800px) and (max-width : 999px) {
  #content { width:800px; }
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 799px) {
  #content { width:600px; }
}
```

Comment: Can you shouw your media queries, please?

Comment: @Michael Sure no problem. I have these two media queries to actually support three types of devices. Desktops ( width > 1000px ), tablets and high-definition smartphones ( width 800-1000px ) and all other phones and devices ( width < 800px ). Problem is (as described in my question) that when I zoom in/out the page on mobile, it keeps changing its viewport and layout keeps changing as well, because layout of the page is different for each type of device. But this is not desired at all. I want one fix layout for each type of device, but to be zoomable.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [the `viewport` meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) to modify the width of the viewport on mobile browsers to be a certain fixed size. This will force the browser to zoom in on initial load based on what the native width of the viewport is. You can use this fixed width as a reference point to set the size of other elements on your page.

For example, if you wanted to set the width of the viewport to be 600px you would include this line in your HTML `<head>`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=600px">
```

You can then set the width of other elements on the page knowing how wide it will be in proportion to the viewport. For example this element will take the whole width of the mobile browser:

```
#content {
   width: 600px;
}
```

Rather than scaling the content to fit the viewport, you can scale the viewport to fit the content.

Answer (score -2):

I would recommend taking a different approach, and use a responsive/adaptive theme with a zoom-limit set.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not change layout. But can you be please more specific what approach would you reccomend ?

Comment: Resize your browser window once you've loaded [this site](http://demo.colorlabsproject.com/?theme=adam-eve).